# How to retrieve the information from the url?

Tags: angularjs

I have a url which has an object which contains name,city then how to display it on a page.

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Angulars $http-Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). It creates a promise which delivers the data and you can use that in your Controller, Service etc.

I created a simple [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tkxj3wCDp1EbAwG5g4Y6?p=preview) which showcases a possible setup.

Code looks something like

```
$http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php').success(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

You can access that data like shown in the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tkxj3wCDp1EbAwG5g4Y6?p=preview).

Have fun!